# Let $n$ be a positive integer. Show that $n$ and $2n$ have the same number of representations as a sum of two squares of non-negative integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

> Let $n$ be a positive integer. Show that $n$ and $2n$ have the same number of representations as a sum of two squares of non-negative integers.
>
> **Hint**: $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2$

Comment: Hint2: $2=1+1=1^2+1^2$

Comment: Using the hint, you could try to show that for every such representation of $n$ there is a unique one for $2n$, and vice versa. @frank000's hint is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

If a pair of numbers $(x_0;y_0)$ it is a solution of $x^2+y^2=n$, then a pair of numbers $(x_0-y_0; x_0+y_0) -$ it is a solution of $x^2+y^2=2n$.

If a pair of numbers $(x_1;y_1)$ it is a solution of $x^2+y^2=2n$, then $x_1, y_1$ of have the same parity and a pair of numbers $\left(\frac{x_1+y_1}{2};\frac{y_1-x_1}{2} \right) -$ it is a solution of $x^2+y^2=n$.